# Is PageRank passed just once?

Tags: seo, pagerank, backlinks

I'd like to know if link juice is passed just once?

For example if I place a link in a website that passes little to no juice today, but 6 months down the road the link is still there but the website now passes a lot of juice... do I get a share of that link juice, or do I get it just once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PageRank is calculated daily. Each time Google runs its algorithm to rank pages it takes the current PR into account. So you get the current PR value of that link.

FYI, websites don't have PR. Web *pages* do. So a home page of a website may have a high PR but its inner pages may not.

Comment: I see, so it's theoretically worthless to get a followed link from a high PR site if the page linking to my site has 0 PR, right?

Comment: If you're chasing PR, yes. But you shouldn't be chasing PR because it has very little effect on your rankings. You should be seeking links from related websites regardless of the PR of its pages.

Comment: but wouldn't it be slightly better to get links from high PR AND related webs pages? There's no need to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: If you can, sure. But PR is worth *a lot* less then you think. It really shouldn't be a factor in anything you do.